Copy Folder From Docker To Server
I was trying to copy folder from my docker container to my server host but while doing docker cp getting below error message
message :- copying between containers is not supported.
How can I copy files from the container to the host.
The command I was trying to execute is docker cp containerName:/folder_path server:/server_path/

One side of docker cp needs to be a local path.  "Remote server" isn't a standard concept in Docker or in Unix in general.  (Do you expect that server:/path syntax to be scp, FTP, rcp, or some other protocol?)  Copy the files to the host system, then as a separate step copy them to the remote system.

You can use the following command
docker cp container_id:/path_to_folder destination

